# Offline wallet.dat storage for large amounts

Tags: wallet, offline

I would like to store my bitcoin wallet offline and need a few pointers. Since this will be my long-term savings storage (decent amount, rarely accessed), I will use one PC (online) with only ubuntu and bitcoin core installed to make the PSBTs and another offline only dedicated PC with wifi/bluetooth/networking removed with only ubuntu and bitcoin core to create wallet.dat and sign PSBTs if needed. Now I want to store wallet.dat in many different places to make sure I never lose access. Couldnt find any detailed guides on this process.

For example is it sufficient to simply encrypt wallet.dat file? I'd like to avoid using 3rd party software as much as possible (like truecrypt) because in 10-20 years the project could be abandoned and it's hard to get the intial trusted software package, etc)

Also what is the best media for long-term storage? CDs, usb stick, microSD? will any of them get bit rot? Remember I need this accessible many decades in the future. I plan to burn the wallet.dat file on a CD thinking this kind of media has little interaction with my PC, as opposed to usb stick which can be backdoored? Any objection to uploading this on the cloud as well (if encrypted that is).

Sorry if this has been answered but all I find is somewhat old and doesn't seem risk averse enough vs the value of bitcoin these days.

Any help appreciated thanks.